# EXC_BAD_ACCESS coming from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, nsnumber

```
NSDictionary *orientation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CIDetectorEyeBlink,
   [NSNumber numberWithInt:imgOrientation], CIDetectorImageOrientation, nil];
```

My app keeps crashing at this line, giving the dreaded `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (code=1, address=0x0). I went through all the contents in the `NSDictionary` named "orientation" and they're all objective c objects. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening? Anything helps because I'm completely lost. This is the entire method in which the line is located:

```
-(void)scanFace{

    UIImageOrientation imgOrientation = imgView.image.imageOrientation;
    orientation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CIDetectorEyeBlink, 
   [NSNumber numberWithInt:imgOrientation], CIDetectorImageOrientation, nil];

    CIImage *newImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imgView.image.CGImage
                                       options:orientation];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
        context:context options:[NSDictionary
      dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

    NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:newImage options:orientation];

    if (features.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"NO FACE %i", features.count);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"FACE FOUND %i", features.count);
    }

    for (CIFaceFeature *feature in features) {

        if (feature.leftEyeClosed == YES) {
            leftLab.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Left Eye Closed"];
        } else {
            leftLab.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Left Eye Open"];
        }
        if (feature.rightEyeClosed == YES) {
            rightLab.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Right Eye Closed"];
        } else {
            rightLab.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Right Eye Open"];
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
0   FaceDetection                       0x000551a7 -[ViewController scanFace] + 66
1   FaceDetection                       0x000550cb __26-[ViewController takePic:]_block_invoke_2 + 282
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3c6ac793 <redacted> + 10
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3c6ac5db <redacted> + 22
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3c6afe45 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 228
5   CoreFoundation                      0x3456b1b1 <redacted> + 1288
6   CoreFoundation                      0x344de23d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
7   CoreFoundation                      0x344de0c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
8   GraphicsServices                    0x380bd33b GSEventRunModal + 74
9   UIKit                               0x363fa2b9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
10  FaceDetection                       0x00055e41 main + 116
11  libdyld.dylib                       0x3c6bfb20 <redacted> + 0
```

Comment: Try to see what values have CIDetectorEyeBlink and CIDetectorImageOrientation, I suspect you got a nil pointer.

Comment: You need to provide more information, there is nothing obviously wrong with your line of code in isolation. Have you examined the stack trace?

Comment: Does anything pop out to you in the rest of the code that I've added?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the crash? At initial glance the code appears to be OK (though not optimal).

Comment: are you running two threads in 'parallel' that could modify orientation

Comment: I'm not running two parallel threads. NSGod: The stack trace was added. How would I interpret that? Also, which parts of my code could I change to optimize it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that *CIDetectorEyeBlink* appeared in iOS 7 !

If you try to use this key in older versions you'll get EXC_BAD_ACCESS because it is undefined.

Starting from iOS7 you won't have problems in this code fragment.